# npm start or using build files for hosting react app in containers is efficient way?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, devops, single-page-application

I found there are two ways to host react app in docker containers. But, It's unable to figure out which is efficient way. Whether I have to run "npm start" in the container or host build files through NODE.js.

Comment: What does npm start do? If it's from Create React App that's the dev server, which you don't want to be using in production. You likely want to host the build outputs, but you can use any web server for that (e.g. I use NGINX here, with some config for push-state routing: https://github.com/textbook/react-ts-fe/blob/7dd5dc2549421bc90cba3e110140300b2ed9a4bd/Dockerfile).

Comment: If you are using `create-react-app` then running `npm start` is only for development. `npm run build` is for creating build folder that can be hosted by your server. They are very different as development is slower than production. This is intentionally made. You can [read more](https://overreacted.io/how-does-the-development-mode-work/)

Answer (score 1):

I feel running build is the best option because, you can directly serve it using Nginx or any serving module... While running npm start is like, running in development mode and also the node process has to be running in the background... And if suppose any error occurs, node will crash and u have to restart it again.. Also.. it's a node server, which is single threaded.. u have to create as many instances of React app to handle the users..

So it's always best to build it and serve it using Nginx or any serving module. You can use Nginx or any serving containers and do the thing...